# Is there a way to convert a decimal number to binary?

Tags: solidity

I am new to Solidity, so please, accept my apologies, if the question is really dumb.
I am trying to write two functions, one of which gets the uint256 and converts it to a binary number, and the other gets the binary input (if that's even possible) and returns a uint256.
Is such a conversion even possible?

Comment: Can you describe more of what you mean by a "binary number?" Do you mean a string representation of binary (e.g. "00000111" to represent 7)? Or do you mean converting between uint256 and bytes32? Or something else?

Comment: I meant converting a 7 00111 (bytes16 I guess). But if this is not possible to do to get a number, I can go with a string representation, with the ability of how to convert it back to a number as an output.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. `bytes16` is a sequence of 16 bytes of data. Those bytes can be anything and can be interpreted any way. (You could use it to store a number of a string.) Maybe you can give an example of the input and the output you want or further explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Another way to maybe help with the confusion... what is a "binary number" to you? (In a computer, all numbers are internally stored as binary, but that's rarely relevant when you write code. `x = 7` involves binary in the CPU, but why do you care?)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I'll try to explain what I mean. I want a function, that takes a two-digit number, and converts it into a binary representation of 5 binary numbers. For example, the input would be 11, and the output would be 01101. Then, I want another function to reverse the input of 01101 to output as 11, if that's possible to do.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do that?

Comment: And to clarify, "the output would be 01101" means the function would output a string (first character: "0", second character: "1", etc.)?

Comment: Yes, the function needs to convert the number to a binary and output as a string. Similarly, it should take a string like that and output as a number. I think that's exactly what I wanted to phrase. I need this for a small research project I'm working on.

Comment: This is certainly doable, but I don't understand why you would do it. Just do it in JavaScript or whatever language you're using to interface with the contract.

Comment: @smarx I thought about that, coding everything on Python, and interface it with the contract, however, thought there might be security loopholes.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If someone is running some Python code and modifies it to do the conversion wrong, all they can do is fool themselves about how binary works. That couldn't possibly affect anyone else.

Comment: Within the Solidity contract, just use numbers (`uint256`). Outside the contract, if someone wants to see the binary representation of the number, they can do the conversion themselves (or, more likely, use client software that does it for them).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I still can't imagine a use for this, but I wrote code to do it because it seemed fun:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Convert {
    function toBinaryString(uint8 n) public pure returns (string) {
        // revert on out of range input
        require(n < 32);

        bytes memory output = new bytes(5);

        for (uint8 i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            output[4 - i] = (n % 2 == 1) ? byte("1") : byte("0");
            n /= 2;
        }

        return string(output);
    }

    function fromBinaryString(bytes5 input) public pure returns (uint8) {
        uint8 n = 0;

        for (uint8 i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            n *= 2;
            if (input[i] == "1") {
                n += 1;
            } else {
                // revert on malformed input
                require(input[i] == "0");
            }
        }

        return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason would be, if you have a set numbers representing different flag states, such as 1, 2, 4,, 8, 16, and you wanted to identify which ones were in your sample number, the simple way would be to Xor your number. but alas you can not do that with an integer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. You can certainly `xor` two integers in Solidity. (Although in the case of checking for flags, don't you want `and`? E.g. `if (flags & 1) ...`, `if (flags & 2) ...`)

Comment: I am working on something similar and tried your suggestion before you replied, and using solidity 0.5.0 in remix I get  the TypeError: Type uint8 is not implicitly convertible to expected type bool.
        if (_restrictionCode & 8) {

Comment: Sorry, try `if (_restrictionCode & 8 != 0)`.